# Web Hosting Management Package

Tags: dns, webserver, hosting

I want to host multiple domains on my Ubuntu VM. Is there any package like Lamp to handle DNS, Email, Apache and other needed softwares for a web server?

I'm looking for a software like Plesk and Cpanel. But an opensource one.

Answer (score 4):

**AlternC:** It is basically a great open source software, which is quite easy to install and use as well.

AlternC is user friendly, and it's capable of managing large hosting services, and offers plenty of features. The licensed AlternC GPL provides automatic installation, configuration and web based control panels. Few of the web services provided by the software are domain control, ftp accounts, email configuration, website statistics, and you can literally do everything that cPanel offers… The documentation and user manuals are available in French, though the translations are available in English too.<sup>[Om Thoke](http://webhosting.about.com/od/Control-Panels/a/5-Cool-Control-Panels-Capable-Of-Competing-With-Cpanel.htm)</sup>

**Baifox:** It is yet another GPL control panel, which is great for managing hosting services. The unique feature of this control panel is that it is lighter than most of the other controls panels; it offloads the work from the server and does not disturb too much either. Hence, the performance of the server remains unaffected, and the CPU consumption low.<sup>[Om Thoke](http://webhosting.about.com/od/Control-Panels/a/5-Cool-Control-Panels-Capable-Of-Competing-With-Cpanel.htm)</sup>

You may also take a look at [ServerPilot](https://serverpilot.io/).  ServerPilot is the best hosting control panel for developers and businesses running their PHP applications on cloud servers.<sup>[ServerPilot](https://serverpilot.io/)</sup>

Comment: I was looking at AlternC and it suggests that the server be Debian. Have you tried it on Ubuntu and/or do you know of any inconsistency or interoperability vis-a-vis Debian?

Comment: It should work with Ubuntu with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried these three systems, which are suggested by vultr.com for their VPS server subscribers -

1. [Virtualmin/Webmin](http://virtualmin.com) - has the most functionality
2. [VestaCP](http://vestacp.com) - is the most fast and simple but has fewer functions
3. [Ajenti](https://github.com/Eugeny/ajenti) - is a bit complicated

You can see [brief review and quick install steps here](https://www.vultr.com/docs/three-free-server-control-panels-with-quick-install) on vultr.com knowledgebase.

But they are not as end-user friendly as WHMCS/Cpanel. I can say they are convenient for experienced developers and webmasters.

**Update** 2015-03-08: I have recently migrated several Cpanel servers to Virtualmin servers on Ubuntu 14.04, and the experience of setting up the servers, as well as migrating the cpanel accounts has been a breeze. Virtualmin has a very user friendly server migration utility.